# Postfix: Run script on AUTH

Tags: postfix

Is it possible to run a script after `AUTH`? I see that [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) reads the log to determine the result of `AUTH`. But is there a way to execute a script without reading the log?

EDIT:

The script will need just the SASL username and should be triggered when AUTH succeeds. Ideally, the script should be executed before the mail is downloaded. Right now I have a pipe executing the script, but the script is executed after the mail is downloaded.

I'm using dovecot with mysql.

Comment: Do you just need to run something on that trigger, or do you need other session information? Do you actually care about AUTH attempts, or is having that information available on authenticated submission of mail good enough? Depending on your needs, it may be more convenient to plug your extra automation into whatever authentication mechanism is used as an effect of the authentication, e.g. in sasld/pam/ldap. Please [edit] your question to describe the problem you are trying to solve in more detail.

Comment: @anx Thanks. I've edited the question.

Comment: The question was why you want to run a script when somebody authenticates? Are you going to implement some kind of audit, or are there something else? I run several mail systems with various requirements and never encountered such a need, so your question looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Probably you have to solve entirely different problem and just chose completely wrong approach. This is why we are asking about the original problem, which you hope to solve by running a script with each authentication.

Comment: Then again questions that @anx asked arose: what information about the session you need in the script, does it need to be able to alter the authentication results (e.g. report failure to not to receive the mail itself) and so on. In principle, I'd integrate that into PAM, authentication layer below Postfix and SASL. Alternatively, you can set up authentication directly against some SQL database advanced enough, write a user-defined function which does all the intereting stuff, and call that function in the authentication query.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I only need the SASL username for the script as each device would have its own username and I'm using dovecot with mysql for authentication. If I were to modify the password query in dovecot to call a user-defined function, I wouldn't be able to tell if the authentication succeeds or not. I'm trying to execute the script only when authentication succeeds.

Comment: That actually depends on what exactly SASL method you use. With CRAM-MD5, DIGEST-MD5, GSSAPI or SRP methods your're right, database can't perform a check. But with PLAIN and LOGIN you could design a query so database will be able to tell was the password correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Postfix [access policy delegation](https://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html) feature.

Postfix will set `sasl_username` and other `sasl_*` attributes in the request to the policy service, but only if the SASL authentication was performed and it was successful.

You can design a Postfix policy service (a.k.a. "the script" which implements the protocol described under the link above), which checks the SASL username and if it founds the login belongs to some predefined set, it replies with `action=reject We don't want to accept the complete message from this client` (denies the mail with some explanatory message). The service is also free to perform unrelated actions, such as writing to the database, sending an SMS and so on. Then you place a call to it *immediately before* call to `permit_sasl_authenticated` that should already exist in some of your `smtpd_*_restrictions` blocks. You also can implement the whole `permit_sasl_authenticated` logic in your script and remove call to it altogether.

Postfix will process the policy service before the DATA command, e.g. before the client has a chance to send any big chunk of data.

---

Another variation of the same idea is to carefully craft `smtpd_sender_login_maps` so that for envelope sender addresses used by selected clients it will return some unrelated value(s) of SASL login, which never happens to be used by those clients to authenticate. Then add `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch` or `reject_known_sender_login_mismatch` immediately before `permit_sasl_authenticated`.

Then Postfix will allow clients to successfully authenticate, but when it comes to the actual SMTP transaction, it will query the "envelope sender address" (presented by the client in the SMTP `MAIL FROM:` command) against the _maps, and reject, because the login which was used by the client will not be present in the returned list of permitted logins for that sender address. Again, Postfix will reject the transaction before the client has a chance to send big chunk of data.

This will release you from writing a script, but also you won't be able to perform arbitrary actions script. The only gain is that it will log who was successfully authenticated into the log file.